# Why India's name is "Bharatvarsha" according to Linga Purana?

Tags: shiva, linga-purana

Why India's name is "Bharatvarsha" according to Linga Purana? Who was Rushabh's son Bharat on his name Nharatvarsha is famous in Linga Puran story?

Comment: Rishabha was the first tirthankar of Jainism who is also known to be an incarnation of Lord Vishnu. According to Jainism, Bharatvarsha was named after his son Bharat but according to Hinduism, Bharatvarsha was named after Bharat, the son of Dushyant and Shakuntala of Hastinapur.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Do you know any scriptures that say that Bharata Varsha was named after Shakuntala's son Bharata?  If so, you can post an answer to this question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/does-shakuntalas-son-bharata-have-a-role-in-the-naming-of-bharatavarsha