# Why Bharata Varsha (India) alone is called Karma Bhoomi?

Tags: india, vishnu-purana

According to [Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp060.htm),

> In Jambu-dwípa, Vishnu, consisting of sacrifice, is worshipped, as
>   the male of sacrificial rites, with sacrificial ceremonies: he is
>   adored under other forms elsewhere. **Bhárata is therefore the best of
>   the divisions of Jambu-dwípa, because it is the land of works: the
>   others are places of enjoyment alone. It is only after many thousand
>   births, and the aggregation of much merit, that living beings are
>   sometimes born in Bhárata as men**. The gods themselves exclaim, "Happy
>   are those who are born, even from the condition of gods, as men in
>   Bhárata-varsha, as that is the way to the pleasures of Paradise, or
>   the greater blessing of final liberation. Happy are they who,
>   consigning all the unheeded rewards of their acts to the supreme and
>   eternal Vishńu, obtain existence in that **land of works**, as their path
>   to him. We know not, when the acts that have obtained us heaven shall
>   have been fully recompensed, where we shall renew corporeal
>   confinement; but we know that those men are fortunate who are born
>   with perfect faculties in Bhárata-varsha."

It also says

> From this region heaven is obtained, or even, in some cases,
>   liberation from existence; or men pass from hence into the condition
>   of brutes, or fall into hell. Heaven, emancipation, a state in
>   mid-air, or in the subterraneous realms, succeeds to existence here,
>   and the world of acts is not the title of any other portion of the
>   universe.

But it doesn't look correct in today's context. There are many people in India who are doing crimes and acquiring bad Karma? Indeed, if we acquire Karma on this land, how can we liberate?

Also, [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10615/3500) answer gives info about other islands and all people on this Earth were descendants of Grandsons of Priyavrata.

- Why only descendants of Bharatha are privileged or Why this Varsha (country) is privileged?
- In Kaliyuga, Sanatana Dharma or Vedic Religion is limited to Bharatha Varsha alone. What about other Yugas? In other Yugas people were present in other islands and were worshiping Vedic Gods. Was Bharatha Varsha still Karma Bhoomi during those times?

Comment: "In other Yugas people were present in other islands and were worshiping OUR GODS",,It should be only Gods or atleast True(or Vedic) Gods,Our Gods does not make any sense just like our Sun  does not. :)

Comment: @Rickross I mean Shiva and Vishnu by "Our Gods". See [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2712/3500) answer.

Comment: Actually, other islands were occupied by Daityas and Danavas. Sage Kashyap(after whom Caspian Sea is called) had several wives, from Aditi came Vivasvan(Surya Deva)-> Vaivasat Manu-> Ishwakus-> inhabitants of Bharat Bhumi. While from [Danu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danu_(Irish_goddess))-> Danavas(inhabitants of European continent)-> Nords(Aesir). From Diti->Daitya(or Titans)->Persians. Also refer [Ahur Mazda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda). But all are human form is same i.e. Sage Kashyap. Aditi was high in Satva, Danu high in Rajas and Diti high in Tamas, hence the difference

Comment: But intermixing was common, like wife of Yayati, Chandravanshi king was Daitya queen [Sharmishta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharmishtha).

Comment: There are many more lines like that of North Asians and Africans, but they dont have historical records . Yavanas/Greeks and Kirats(East Asians) are mentioned in several texts like [Mahabharat](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-the-Santhals-believe-that-they-were-invaded-and-oppressed-by-the-Aryans).

Comment: @RaviJ people of which continents or countries have Satva, Rajas and Tamas? Why other countries are called "bhoga" bhoomis?

Comment: Nord race of Europe covering of Denmark, Swedan and surrounding regions, America, Australia have link to Rajsik Goddess Danu and her [sons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuatha_D%C3%A9_Danann). This can also be seen as how much openly importance to lust is given in those regions for example in their movies. While Persian/Assyrian race occupying Arabian continents like Afghanisthan, Iraq etc., are offsprings of Diti and so their so much [violence and wars] (http://hinduwebsite.com/zoroastrianism/indoiranian.asp) happen in those regions.

Comment: Vedic India's condition was changed to Tamsik because of rule by Persian Mughals which caused huge downfall of status of women class and loss of scientific Yoga, rituals, leaving behind superstitions. The condition was improved by Rajsik Britishers, but it also brought huge materialistic approach among Indians of today who see the goal of life to earn material possessions only. India is karma bhumi, because here alone, 4 paths of liberation that are Bhakti, Gyan, Karma and Kriya Yoga are clearly and openly defined from time to time by sages. People in other continents consider Maya as real.

Comment: In ancient India, it was compulsory for everyone to go through 4 Ashramas, that are Brahmacharya, Grihastha, Vanaprastha and Sanyass. In time of Buddha, everyone entered Sanyass directly. But see what condition of India has been made by rule of Britishers and Mughals. Liberation was easily obtained through Sanyass and heavens through Grihastha in ancient India.

Comment: You ask "But it doesn't look correct in today's context. There are many people in India who are doing crimes and acquiring bad Karma? Indeed, if we acquire Karma on this land, how can we liberate?"  But the Vishnu Purana says "From this region heaven is obtained, or even, in some cases, liberation from existence; or men pass from hence into the condition of brutes, or fall into hell."  It doesn't say everyone who lives in India is liberated.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yeah, not all people of India will liberate.But can we say all other lands as "Bhoga" Bhumis?

Comment: Yeah, I've always found Hindu scriptures' various statements about India rather strange.  There are statements that India is the only place where people incur good and bad karma for their actions, statements that the four Yugas only apply to India, etc. I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can you tell me where is this statement about 4 yugas only applying to india?

Comment: @Anisha it can be found in Puranas. One such reference can be found in description of Bharata and other dvipas in Puranas. Check Anusanga of Brahmanda Purana (don't remember exact chapter now).

Answer (score 1):

The questions are:

> - Why only descendants of Bharatha are privileged or Why this Varsha (country) is privileged?
> - In Kaliyuga, Sanatana Dharma or Vedic Religion is limited to Bharatha Varsha alone. What about other Yugas? In other Yugas people
>     were present in other islands and were worshiping Vedic Gods. Was
>     Bharatha Varsha still Karma Bhoomi during those times?

---

I am not considering the Yuga concept as correct, and hence my answer does not provide material for 2nd part of the question about nature of people in other Yugas in other regions.

---

Rig Veda III.30.5 (composed by **Sage Viswamitra**) says

> indra dṛhya yāmakośā abhūvan yajñāya śikṣa ghṛṇate sakhibhyaḥ |
>   durmāyavo durevā martyāso niṣaṅghiṇo ripavo hantvāsaḥ ||
>
> Indra, be firm, for there are obstructors of (thy)path : secure to the
>   worshipper and his friends : the means of completing the sacrifice :
>   **mortal enemies bearing bows, armed with mischievous weapons , and
>   coming with evil intent**, must be destroyed by thee.

---

- So by the time this mantra was composed, we can infer that people with evil intentions did exist and tried to obstruct the spiritual practices of the sages.
- At another mantra, there was a description of a woman conceives a baby in secret .  (Rig Veda II.29.1)

> UPHOLDERS of the Law, ye strong Ādityas, remove my sin ***like her who
>   bears in secret***. You, Varuṇa, Mitra and all Gods who listen, I call to
>   help me, I who know your goodness.

So vices that we observe in present generation, must have co-existed, alongwith enlightened people,  in that era also, though the degree of their presence  cannot be ascertained now.

Did not we see in our generation, Sages like Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Sri Ramana Maharshi, etc, in spite of falling values in the society?

---

Bacteria, which are harmful as well as helpful to human body, will always be present in and around Human bodies.

A human body is considered healthy only if the domination of helpful bacteria is more and ill- healthy, if contrary situation exist.

---

Coming to the core question - **Why only descendants of Bharatha are privileged or Why this Varsha (country) is privileged?** -, it is to be understood that it is a misconception.

It is true that in India, the atmosphere is more conducive to SPIRITUAL practices.  It ***does not mean*** that everyone, who takes birth in India is SPIRITUAL by default.

It also does not mean that people, who takes birth in other countries are, per se, materialistic.

People like Vedacharya David Frawley, Dr. Paul Brunton, etc, are examples of non-Indian, SPIRITUALLY oriented people.

Answer (score 0):

We can't comment on the present situation if currently India can be called the 'Karma Bhūmī' or not. However, for the previous ages, when Dharma was in its zenith, a Gauḍīya acharya gives some perspective, for that time:-

The Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇavism acharya - Śrīla Bhaktivedānta [Nārāyaṇa Gosvāmī](https://www.purebhakti.com/teachers/srila-gurudeva) Mahārāja gives an explanation for this in his commentary called 'Sārārtha-Varṣiṇī Prakāśikā-vṛtti', which itself is a commentary on Sārārtha-Varṣiṇī Ṭīkā (which is a commentary by Śrīla [Viśvanātha Cakravartī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visvanatha_Chakravarti) Ṭhākura on the Śrīmada Bhāgvad Gītā).

Anyway, here's what Nārāyaṇa Gosvāmī comments on BG 18.41, I'm just giving the small relevant part of the full commentary:

> “Although varṇa-dharma is partially accepted in Europe, it has not
> been established in its full, scientifically-based form. Wherever
> knowledge and civilization make real progress, varṇa-dharma manifests
> proportionately. Two methods are employed in any activity: the
> unscientific and the scientific. An activity is performed
> unscientifically until a scientific process is accepted. For example,
> before the invention of power driven ships, people used to travel in
> sailboats, designed to depend on the winds. But when scientifically
> manufactured steam ships were introduced, they replaced sailing
> vessels as the primary means of water transport. The same principle
> can also be applied to society. Until the caste system becomes
> properly established in a country, that country’s society will be run
> by some unscientific, rudimentary system. **A rudimentary and primitive
> caste system is currently operating in and controlling societies in
> all countries of the world, save and except for India [where it is
> more developed]**. **India has therefore been called *karma-kṣetra*, the
> land where prescribed duty is properly executed.”**

The full commentary can be read [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc420335.html).

So, basically, as per Śrīla Nārāyaṇa Gosvāmī, India (Bhārat Varṣa) is specifically called Karma Bhūmī on account of it being the role-model in the implementation and adherence of the varṇāśrama dharma system. Since almost everyone used to perform their karma as per their prescribed varṇa-dharma, thus it was(is) known as the Karma Bhūmī.