# Why India is Known as Karma-Bhumi?

Tags: scripture, india

I often heard the term Karma-Bhumi, and also heard that India is Karma-Bhumi? So any one Know or is there any evidence in scriptures? Kindly share.

Comment: You may look this: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10977/why-bharata-varsha-india-alone-is-called-karma-bhoomi