# How did India get its name as Bharat?

Tags: mahabharata, history, india

I tried to google this question and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_%28emperor%29) it is not very clear.

The above [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_%28emperor%29) suggests that India is called Bharat because of Emperor Bharata (son of Shakuntala and Dhushyant) whereas [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_Chakravartin) suggests it is named after Bharata Chakravartin (Gomateshwar).

Which story is the correct one?

Comment: not sure if this is a question related to Hinduism. I ll let the mods decide

Comment: @PratikBhat It's definitely related to Hinduism; Shakuntala's son Bharata and Rishabha's son Bharata are both prominent kings mentioned in Hindu scripture, and Hindu scripture does discuss the naming of Bharata Varsha.  But it's a duplicate.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Thanks for clarifying my doubts!

Comment: Question is not duplicate, there's ambiguity here, which needs to be resolved.

Comment: Please edit wikipedia pages according if it is clear

Comment: @BharatBanavalikar See this question [In which Mahayuga and Manvantara, King Bharatha lived after whom India is called as Bharath](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10614/3500). Bharatha was Grandson of Priyavrata and all continents and countries were named just after creation of Earth. Many Puranas say Bharata as son of Rishaba. Only Mahabharata says He was shankuntala's son.

Comment: @Destroyer , So you mean to say that both the bharata's here are the same person?

Comment: Nope. Shakuntala's son was recent.  He was ancestor of Shantanu. But Bharatha, Rishab's son was responsible for name of India. After creation of Earth, all places on Earth were given names of Grandsons of Swayambhuva Manu. We live in 28th Kali Yuga of Vaivastara Manvantara (7th Manvantara) and Bharatha might have lived in this or previous Mahayuga (not sure). But Rishab's son lived during the beginning of Kalpa, just after earth was formed in Swayambhuva Manvantara (1st Tretayuga and 1st Manvantara).

Comment: @TheDestroyer I don't know what you mean by "Only Mahabharata says He was shankuntala's son."  What is the statement that the Mahabharata makes that other scriptures do not?  Is it that there was a king named Bharata who was a son of Shakuntala?  Numerous other scriptures mention that, including both the Vedas and the Puranas.  Is it that India is named after the son of Shakuntala?  I don't know of any mentions of that in the Mahabharata.  So I'm not sure where you think the Mahabharata differs from the Puranas on this issue.

Comment: @TheDestroyer By the way, there were several generations between Priyavarta and Rishabha's son Bharata, so it's not so clear to me that Bharata lived in the first Treta Yuga.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Actually what i meant was that India is named after Shakuntala's son Bharatha is only mentioned in Mahabhartaha. Puranas say Rishab's son Bharatha is responsible for name of India. There were two Bharathas. Shakunta's son and Rishab' son.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Does Vyasa Mahabhartha never mention India is named after Shakuntala's son, Bharatha? Then why  do people cite Mahabharatha for it. Maybe this is mentioned in another version of Mahabharatha. Myself read an abridged version of Mahabharatha and not sure of it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Priyavrata- Agnidhara- Nabhi- Rishabha- Bhartha. Yeah, Nabhi lived during  1st Treta Yuga of Swayambhuva Manvantara and Bharatha might have lived during Kali Yuga of 1st Mahayuga or Satya Yuga of 2nd Mahayuga.

Comment: May be the discussion is turned out, which is superior Mahabharata or other Puranas.. Which one to believe?

Comment: @TheDestroyer "We live in 28th Kali Yuga of Vaivastara Manvantara (7th Manvantara) and Bharatha might have lived in this or previous Mahayuga (not sure)" Shakuntala's son Bharata had to have lived in a previous Mahayuga, because he was the adopted father of the sage Bharadwaja, son of Brihaspati, and Bharadwaja was there in earlier Mahayugas.  He's mentioned in the Ramayana, for instance.  Any story involving the sage Bharadwaja or the sage Dirghatamas happened during or after the time of Bharata.

Comment: @BharatBanavalikar Well, the issue doesn't arise, because as far as I know there's no contradiction between the Mahabharata and the Puranas on this subject.