# When did Vishnu's bird Garuda try to kill Vishnu's serpent Adiseshan?

Tags: vishnu, adisesha, agamas, garuda

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36), the Pancharatra Agamas are the foundational texts of Vaishnavism.  Similarly, the foundational texts of Shaivism are known as the Shaiva Agamas, aka the Shaiva Tantras.  One of the Shaiva Agamas is known as the Parakhya Tantra, and it takes the form of a dialogue between the sage Prakasha and his student Pratoda.

In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzzln.jpg) from the Parakhya Tantra, Prakasha describes the geography of Jambudvipa, the continent where India is located.  (Some people equate Jambudvipa with the entire Earth or even something larger than the Earth, but that's a discussion for another time.). In particular, he says this:

> To the south of Ilavrita is the mountain called Nishadha, on which Garuda had been poised to kill the serpent Shesha and was forbidden.

My question is, what's the story of Vishnu's bird Garuda trying to kill Vishnu's serpent Adiseshan?

Now I'm aware that Garuda has a long-standing enmity with snakes, due to the fact that he and his mother Vinata were enslaved by the Nagas (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2964/36)) who were the sons of Vinata's co-wife Kadru.  Garuda even got a boon from Indra that snakes would be his natural food, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01035.htm) of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata.  And Adiseshan is the eldest son of Kadru.  But I find it strange that one attendant of Vishnu would try to kill another.  Could this story have taken place before one or both of them became attendants of Vishnu?

The only story I know of where Garuda and Adiseshan fight is the story of Arulmaakadal Perumal Vishnu temple in Mahabalipuram.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sthalasayana_Perumal_Temple,_Tirusirupuliyur#Religious_importance) is what Wikipedia says:

> Once Garuda and Adiseshan (the snake on whom Vishnu rests in his abode Vaikunta) got into an argument as to who was more powerful and devoted to their lord. Finding Garuda a little arrogant, Vishnu went in favour of Adisesha. Worried that Garuda might be angered at this, Adisesha sought the protection of Vishnu, upon which Vishnu asked him to roll himself and hide under him. It is said that as a result of this anger, Garuda never flies over this place.

But is this the same incident as what took place on the Nishadha mountain?

Also, the Parakhya Tantra says "Garuda had been poised to kill the serpent Shesha and was forbidden."  So who forbade him?  I assume the answer is Vishnu, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is 'had been poised Sesha'? The sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Surya Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Was it Indra or Lord Vishnu, who gave boon of killing snakes to Garuda?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan [The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-features/tp-fridayreview/the-bird-versus-the-serpent/article942225.ece) says legend can be found in Garuda Purana.

Comment: @AnilKumar Indra was the one who gave him the boon that snakes would be his natural food.  Vishnu gave him the boons that he would be above Vishnu (on Vishnu's flagpole) and that he would have immortality without having to drink Amrita, as described in an earlier chapter of the Adi Parva: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01034.htm

Comment: The Hindu article is just talking about the story of the Arulmakadal Perumal temple, but as I said in my question I'm not sure if this is the same story as the one where Garuda is stopped from killing Adiseshan on the Nishadha mountain.  In any case, at least at first glance I can't seem to find either story in the Garuda Purana.

Comment: Is this mentioned in any other purana? There is a story about garuda and vasuki fighting but have not heard of garuda and sesha fighting.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Well, when you say "any other purana", I'm not sure whether it's in any Purana at all.  I just found it in a Shaiva Agama called the Parakhya Tantra.

Comment: Keshav- I found a reference to this story in Yoga Vasishta , when kAka bhUsunDa talks about his longevity.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I'm extremely skeptical of the authenticity of the Yoga Vasishta, but I'm still interested in what it has to say.  What is the location of the fight according to the Yoga Vasishta?  Is it Mount Nishada?  Because if it's not Mount Nishada, then it could be a reference to the story of the Arulmakadal Perumal temple, rather than to the story alluded to in the Parakhya Tantra.

Comment: I saw one mention in relation to the stability of the tree on which sage kAka dwells. He says the tree (as well as the mountain on which the tree lives) remained undisturbed during several catclysmic historical occurences. He lists these and one among them is the fight between the snake that holds the earth (has to be adisesha) and rudra in the form of Garuda. Not sure if there are further mentions.

Comment: Why do you feel Yoga Vasishta is inauthentic?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Because it's only in more recent manuscripts that it takes the form of a dialogue between Vasishta and Rama.  In all the older manuscripts it's a philosophical work called the Mokshopaya which has no mentions of Rama and Vasishta.  Plus I don't think any other scriptures even mention the existence of the Yoga Vasishta.  Now if someone were to try to convince me that this is a genuine scripture unrelated to Rama and Vasishta, I might be willing to listen.  I just don't think Vasishta ever spoke these words to Rama.

Comment: Would you have a link to the proper mOkshopAya? Thank you.