# Why did Agni serve as the priest for two kings?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, agni, aitareya-brahmana

In my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7395/36), I discussed an excerpt from the Aitareya Brahmana of the Rig Veda which lists various kings who have performed the Rajasuya Yagna, the ritual to become an emperor.  Now [here](http://gdurl.com/MRS5) is another excerpt from the Aitareya Brahmana which lists various kings who have performed the Rajasuya Yagna, along with the priests who officiated:

> This food Rama Margaveya proclaimed to Vishvanta Saushadamana... This also Tura Kavasheya proclaimed to Janamejaya Parikshita; this Parvata and Narada proclaimed to Somaka Sahadevya, to Sahadeva Sarnjaya, Babhru Daivavridha, Bhima of Vidarbha, Nagnajit of Gandhara; **this Agni proclaimed to Sanshruta Arimdama and to Kratuvid Janaki**; this Vasishta proclaimed to Sudas Paijavana.  All of them attained greatness having partaken of this food.  All of them were great kings; like Aditya, established in prosperity, they gave heat obtaining tribute from all the quarters.  Like Aditya, established in prosperity, he gives heat, from all the quarters he obtains tribute, dread his sway and unassailable, who as a Kshatriyas when sacrificing partakes thus of this food.

"Proclaiming the food" is a description of one of the parts of the Rajasuya Yagna, by the way.  In any case, some of these kings are regognizable; Janamajeya son of Parikshit was Arjuna's great-grandson, Nagnajit of Gandhara was Shakuni's uncle as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7415/36), and Sudas Paijavana was the victor of the famous Battle of Ten Kings as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/823/36).

But my question is about Sanashruta Arindama and Kratuvid Janaki.  Who are these two kings, and why would Agni the fire god serve as the priest for their Rajasuya Yagnas?

Kratuvid Janaki might be related to Sita's father Janaka.  But do any other scriptures mention Sanashruta and Kratuvid, and/or describe their interaction with Agni the fire god?

Comment: I think Rig veda verse one answers your question, `Agnimile purohitam` which literally means salute to agni who is purohit, purohit is a term for preist, so that is why he served as a preist.

Comment: @Yogi That's referring to the fact that he's the priest of the gods.  It has nothing to do with him serving as priest for two human kings.

Comment: Then the human kings might have deviya qualities or they might have obtained something more than devas like bramhajnana

Comment: @Yogi Yeah, I assume the answer is that they were great kings who did something to please Agni, but I'm looking for the details.

Comment: Interesting question!